# Junit 4.11 tests unrooted in eclipse but runs in maven test

Tags: spring, eclipse, maven-3, junit4

I am stuck with some unitary tests that i launch in eclipse, and prints this exception :

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.isPresent(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;)Z

 at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.<clinit>(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:99)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
...
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.<init>(JUnit4TestReference.java:33)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestMethodReference.<init>(JUnit4TestMethodReference.java:25)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:54)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:38)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:444)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

The tests run in test phase in maven build, but fails from eclipse. I use SpringJUnit4Runner class

Comment: A NoSuchMethodError at runtime indicates that you are using a different version jar .

Comment: You are right i added a dependency to my project with and older version of junit. I removed that dependency, and it fixed my problem, thank you.